# Yelp-style google map that follows the user up and down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I would like to have a google map on my page in its own column, that will slide up and down to match the scroll height of the browser window. I've seen this functionality on a few sites (yelp comes to mind). Does anyone know a good jQuery plugin that implements this functionality? I am not even sure how to search for such a plugin because I'm not exactly sure what to call it.

Edit: Using Alley's solution, I came up with this as the final answer:

```
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var $map = $('#mymap');
            var locMin = 0;
            var locMax = $map.parent().height() - $map.height()
            var dif = $(window).height() / 2 - $map.height() / 2;
            var loc = dif + $(window).scrollTop() - $map.parent().offset().top;
            if (loc > locMax)
                loc = locMax;
            if (loc < locMin)
                loc = locMin;
            $map.css('top', loc);

        })
```

make sure to use CSS to make the `#mymap` element to be `position: relative`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrote one quickly for you:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($('#map').offset().top <= 0) {
    $('#map').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, left: '50%', 'margin-left': YOUR PAGE WIDTH / 2 - $('#map').width() })
  } else {
    $('#map').css({ position: 'relative', top: 'auto', left: 'auto', margin:0 })    
  }
})
})
```

Comment: That didn't totally work for me. Could you describe the accompanying DOM structure?

Comment: Well, i just assumed there is a div with the id of 'map'. Just modify the first css() with the properties to set it to the position you want on the screen when scrolled, and the second to reset the css to the original.